# Call these from any controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, methods

I have the following in an initializer:

```
@fedex ||= Pigeons::Fedex.new(
  ENV['FEDEX_KEY'],
  ENV['FEDEX_PASSWORD'],
  ENV['FEDEX_ACCOUNT'],
  ENV['FEDEX_METER']
)
```

I basically want to be able to call `@fedex.track` from any controller.

But right now when I try to call `@fedex.track` I get `NoMethodError: undefined method 'track' for nil:NilClass`

So, what am I doing wrong to be able to make that work?

Comment: An instance variable in an initializer isn't magically an instance variable in other classes. Why do you specifically want to call `@fedex.track` from controllers? Why isn't it enough to create a constant, or get retrieve an instance from configuration, or put it as a module/class variable, or...?

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm trying to centralize these. There will eventually be 100+ of them. So, having them all in one place so I can easily do a `@carrier_xyz.example_method` from any controller or method would be really helpful.

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm not necessarily opposed to another setup here...I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: Same way as exposing any other constant value, but you need to actually *put* in somewhere, like a module::class constant, in the configuration (I might not for this, although you could put the class there maybe), etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose what DaveNewton is saying is:

```
FEDEX ||= Pigeons::Fedex.new(
  ENV['FEDEX_KEY'],
  ENV['FEDEX_PASSWORD'],
  ENV['FEDEX_ACCOUNT'],
  ENV['FEDEX_METER']
)
```

Comment: Or my preference, which would be to put them in a module/class.

Comment: @DaveNewton Can you add an example as an answer? That'd be really helpful.

Comment: @Shpigford Is basically the same thing, but inside a module/class so it's in an isolated namespace.

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanted to do what you asked, you could setup a before filter:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   before_filter :copy_instance_variables_from_initializers

private

  def copy_instance_variables_from_initializers
    TOPLEVEL_BINDING.eval("instance_variables").each |ivar|
      instance_variable_set(ivar.to_s, TOPLEVEL_BINDING.eval(ivar.to_s))
  end

end
```

---

This isn't something you would want to use in production as the other comments/answers show.